# Was the SSR created for the MCU specifically or did it exist in the comics?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, shield

I know that in the MCU the SSR is the precursor to S.H.I.E.L.D. However, did it exist in any form in the comics?

Comment: Movies only AFAICT - http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Strategic_Scientific_Reserve_(Earth-199999)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Strategic Science Reserve was invented for the Marvel Cinematic Universe. In the mainstream Marvel comics (Earth-616), Nick Fury worked up the idea for SHIELD after seeing HYDRA's exploits in World War II; eventually the UN found those plans, and presented them to the US, who formed SHIELD as a branch of the US government, in secret (even from Fury, at first).

The formation of the SSR during World War II is a pretty obvious reference to real-world clandestine groups, like the British [Special Operations Executive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_Operations_Executive) or the United States's [Office of Strategic Services](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_of_Strategic_Services), though those groups were more heavily involved in espionage than the SSR. The folding of the SSR and merging with the newly-formed SHIELD also mirrors the eventual folding of the OSS after the war; the OSS research branch became the [Bureau of Intelligence and Research](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bureau_of_Intelligence_and_Research) while the spy operations eventually became part of the CIA.

---

However, the SSR has appeared at least once in the comics, *after* it appeared in the movies. [Spider-Gwen](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Gwendolyne_Stacy_(Earth-65)) is an alternate-reality Gwen Stacy from what's been called Earth-65; in *Spider-Gwen vol 2 #2*, we see an Earth-65 version of the SSR that turns Sam Wilson into Captain America:

[image: Earth-65 SSR and Project Rebirth]

Comment: It's perhaps worth mentioning that the SSR is clearly based on the real [SOE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_Operations_Executive) - Special Operations Executive.

Comment: I actually got more of an OSS -> CIA feel to it, though the OSS wasn't particularly science-based.

Comment: The SOE did a lot of "ungentlemanly weapons" research during the war.